# How can I filter pivot table position in VBA?

Tags: excel, pivot, vba

I've tried finding an answer to this on this site and I'm having no luck so hopefully someone can help me. I can't provide an example sheet as the data is private, but I will attach a screen shot.

[This is the graph and pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEnc0.png)

I am wanting to try and remove the bottom two lines (Blank and the >15/5/18). The 15/5/18 date changes daily, so I can't reference it by name, and if I try to hide the one called blank, I get a 1004 error.

```
Sub removeblanks()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Due Date")

For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
    pi.Visible = False 'Hide each by default, then show only the ones we want
    If pi.Value = "Jan" Then pi.Visible = True
    If pi.Value = "Feb" Then pi.Visible = True
    If pi.Value = "Mar" Then pi.Visible = True
    If pi.Value = "Apr" Then pi.Visible = True
    If pi.Value = "May" Then pi.Visible = True
    If pi.Value = "Jun" Then pi.Visible = True
    If pi.Value = "Jul" Then pi.Visible = True
    If pi.Value = "Aug" Then pi.Visible = True
    If pi.Value = "Sep" Then pi.Visible = True
    If pi.Value = "Oct" Then pi.Visible = True
    If pi.Value = "Nov" Then pi.Visible = True
    If pi.Value = "Dec" Then pi.Visible = True
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True   end sub
```

I tried other ways but none of them worked, and this was giving me the most success as I could hide or show the month fields, but once I try to hide the others, it errors.

In my picture I have 0 values, and in my data I have months with no data. These need to appear in this chart which is why it shows zero values, so I can't hide lines with no data.

There is a sort going on on VBA which puts everything in order, so the two lines I want gone will always be lines 13 & 14.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are the due dates from multiple years? If so, your pivoting is wrong since you are showing only the months and Feb in year 1 will be added to Feb in year 2 and Feb in year 3 ...

But nevertheless, in a date column of a pivot table are blanks lower than the minimal given date = blank = 0 = 1900-01-00. And then there is an item greater than the maximal given date. Both the dates are variable. But the following should work:

```
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Due Date")

For Each pit In pf.PivotItems
 pit.Visible = True
 If Left(pit.Name, 1) = "<" Then 'lower than the minimal given date = blank = 0 = 1900-01-00
  pit.Visible = False '
 End If
 If Left(pit.Name, 1) = ">" Then 'greater than the maximal given date
  pit.Visible = False '
 End If
Next
```

Comment: The due dates are from multiple years, but it is a 12 month rolling count. I have some VBA code that adds a date filter for time between now and a year ago if that makes sense?

I have just tried your code, and I am still getting error 1004, 'unable to set visible property of the PivotItem class. When I press debug it highlights 'Pi.visible = true'

Comment: Then I cannot help since it works for me. But as often with pivot table questions there are much other things which can be wrong and without having the source data and all of the used VBA, helping is nearly impossible then.

Comment: Ok, thats fair enough thanks for trying. I will try to see what is causing this issue then as it might be able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure that it will always be lines 13&14 did you try something like this?

```
Pi.Visible = True
If Pi.Position > 12 Then
 Pi.Visible = False
End If
```

inside your for loop.

Comment: I'm 99% sure. I have a piece of code that sorts everything into order, which puts these two at the bottom. If I replace what is in my for loop with your code, I get the error 1004, unable to set visible propert of the pivotitem class. When I debug, it highlights the first line of your code

Comment: I see it creates the same issue for both my answer and answer of Axel Richter. When you debug you should be able to identify what is the Pi that caused the error in the Locals window. Could you see what position or name that is?

Comment: The name of it is showing as "<01/10/2015" and it's showing its position as -2146826246. It has a source name that is error 2042

Comment: ok, that position means it is hidden. I am only wondering how it got to that "<01/10/2015" because you dont even have it in the printscreen. Is it removed using another filter? I mean when you filter the vendor does this item disappear?

Comment: Do you have another pivot table just below the pivot table you are using in this macro? Because if I try to show so many lines so it would overlap pivot table that is just below this one it shows Error 1004 Unable to set the visible property of the PivotItem class. So exactly what it shows to you.

Comment: I don't have another pivot table, but something I didn't mention which never occurred to me is that these dates are grouped. So if I ungroup there shows a record for everyday in the last 3 years. So I group the data by month, then filter for just the dates I need. Could this be the issue?  Another thing I have noticed in the locals windows is the sourcenamestandard is "<10/1/2015", but it shows the value as "<01/10/2015" Could this also be an issue?

Comment: I dont think either of those are issue. I created it in the way you describe it and tried macro from answer of Axel Richter and it works fine for me just like it worked for him.

Comment: I know this would seem irrelevant but are you by any chance in the US? Something I've just been reading about error 2042 shows an issue with the UK locale on dates? If this is the case I am a step closer to solving my issue

Comment: nope. I am from Czech Republic. My Excel is set to english, but my date format has Czech Locale = "14.3.2012"

Comment: try this thing - write there an IF stantement to skip the "<10/1/2015" to see if it will crash when it tries to show another one or it finishes without error. If it crashes on next show that I would bet there is some conflict on the sheet... something else than another pivot

Comment: I added "if not pit = "<10/1/2015" then do alex's code" which errored on a different date, which is the >15/05/2018 date

Comment: but that one was visible was it not?

Comment: Yes, on the table that is the one at the bottom along with (blank). It's position for this one is position 0

Comment: I have also tried running your code again with the first pi.visible = true line taken out and I get a RTE 13 type mismatch

Comment: so whatever I try I am unable to get the same error as you have (1004). In this case I guess it probably really is some version-language/format problem...

Comment: I've just been on a skype call with a colleague from across the pond, the file works fine on his computer, it comes up with the error over here. We have come up with a way around it that is not a fix, but we have no idea how to solve the actual issue at hand. Thanks for all the help, sorry we never got anywhere